# Get all attributes for elements in XML file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse a file and get all of the attributes for each `<row>` tag in the file. The file looks generally like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<report>
  <table>
    <columns>
      <column name="month"/>
      <column name="campaign"/>
      <!-- many columns -->
    </columns>
    <rows>
  <row month="December 2009" campaign="Campaign #1" 
       adgroup="Python" preview="Not available" 
       headline="We Write Apps in Python" 
       and="many more attributes here" />
  <row month="December 2009" campaign="Campaign #1" 
       adgroup="Ruby" preview="Not available" 
       headline="We Write Apps in Ruby" 
       and="many more attributes here" />
  <!-- many such rows -->
</rows></table></report>
```

Here is the full file: http://pastie.org/7268456#2.

I've looked at every tutorial and answer I can find on various help boards but they all assume the same thing- I'm searching for one or two specific tags and just need one or two values for those tags. I actually have 18 attributes for each `<row>` tag and I have a mysql table with a column for each of the 18 attributes. I need to put the information into an object/hash/array that I can use to insert into the table with ActiveRecord/Ruby.

I started out using Hpricot; you can see the code (which is not relevant) in the edit history of this question.

Comment: Do not use a link to your XML. *WHEN* the link breaks your question will be pretty worthless to future searches for the same question. Instead, embed the minimum XML needed to demonstrate the problem. Also, using a link forces us to chase down the materials needed to answer your question. We're not paid, we're volunteers, and you're wasting our time by assuming we'll do that, so, please give us what we need to help you.

Comment: Also, your tag and title and question text say Nokogiri, but your source is only for Hpricot. Have you attempted to use Nokogiri? If so, where is that code? I hope you don't expect someone will write/port the code for you. Again, you need to give us the information needed to help you.

Comment: I'm new to web scraping and unfortunately I'm realizing that im working through a book that is outdated(practical reporting with ruby and rails chapter 13) and at every turn I'm running into code examples that don't work. I was using Nokogiri in irb, and unfortunately after 12 hours of frustration yesterday, I shutdown my computer and all my nokogiri code is gone. Ill attempt to re-create it and get back to where I was before I post again. Thanks for the lessons learned, and I apologize for wasting everyone's time...

Comment: Rule one, do NOT write code in IRB or any other REPL in any other language. *Test snippet ideas* in them after you've written the code in your editor and saved the file. Rule two: Don't trust computers to be stable because they're not, some things take longer to crash but all software eventually reaches some sort of entropy, either becoming locked up, or going totally chaotic and exploding. hPricot was the old hotness many years ago but Nokogiri is the new hotness and remains so. And, the internet is a vast garbage heap so be careful what you pick up or step in; Old stuff starts to smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML(my_xml_string)
doc.css('row').each do |row|
  # row is a Nokogiri::XML::Element
  row.attributes.each do |name,attr|
     # name is a string
     # attr is a Nokogiri::XML::Attr
    p name => attr.value
  end
end
#=> {"month"=>"December 2009"}
#=> {"campaign"=>"Campaign #1"}
#=> {"adgroup"=>"Python"}
#=> {"preview"=>"Not available"}
#=> {"headline"=>"We Write Apps in Python"}
#=> etc.
```

Alternatively, if you just want an array of hashes mapping attribute names to string values:

```
rows = doc.css('row').map{ |row| Hash[ row.attributes.map{|n,a| [n,a.value]} ] }
#=> [
#=>  {"month"=>"December 2009", "campaign"=>"Campaign #1", adgroup="Python", … },
#=>  {"month"=>"December 2009", "campaign"=>"Campaign #1", adgroup="Ruby", … },
#=>  …
#=> ]
```

The [`Nokogiri.XML`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri.html#method-c-XML) method is the simplest way to parse an XML string and get a [`Nokogiri::Document`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html) back.

The [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) method is the simplest way to find all the elements with a given name (ignoring their containment hierarchy and any XML namespaces). It returns a [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html), which is very similar to an array.

Each [`Nokogiri::XML::Element`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Element.html) has an [`attributes`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-attributes) method that returns a Hash mapping the name of the attribute to a [`Nokogiri::XML::Attr`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Attr.html) object containing all the information about the attribute (name, value, namespace, parent element, etc.)

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver! Thank you so much for helping me see an example that actually works! It definitely has helped me overcome my frustration and I can get back to learning, I owe you one big time! (both examples worked flawlessly)